# Database Approve Reject WorkFlow

Tags: sql-server, database, nhibernate, workflow, relational-database

I want to implement approve reject workflow using relational database. Currently i am using MS-SQL database along with NHibernate.

Example:

Lets say i have below entry in database

```
ID  Name    Location    FromDate    ToDate  ApprovalStatus
1   ABCD    London       1-Jan      31-Dec  approved
```

now the logged in user can change the entry using front end... which will go for approval

```
ID  Name    Location    FromDate    ToDate  ApprovalStatus
1   ABCD    London      1-Jan       30-Jun  edited
```

If the authority approves the editing then the edits should stay, but if the changes are rejected the i want to revert back the old entry.

There are few ways to implement this, but all of them need lot of boilerplate code for each table and i have around 20-30 such entities which follow the approval process as shown above. The options I can think of are

> 1.create another table which is replica of original table to   maintain the edited entries/ approval workflow. just .
>
> pros: easy to manage, just replace replace the original     entry in
>   case of approval, delete in case of reject
>
> cons: too many duplicate tables + similar number of duplicate domain
>   classes

OR

> 2.use same table, but create duplicate row, which keep track of the  parent row and does appropriate changes on approval/rejection.
>
> pros: reduces unnecessary tables & domain classes
>
> cons: really complex to manage

---

I think the scenario is pretty common and there must be some material/ framework/ architecture addressing this issue. though i am not able to find out anything relevant even after much googling...

please help...

Comment: If an edit gets rejected, you say that you want to revert back to the original, are you intending to record the rejection somewhere?

Comment: no...i don't want to keep the rejection details...

Answer (score 3):

One object: Table + View

First, define a (single) table. This is psuedo code -- I’m guessing at your datatypes and ignoring nullability, you’d need to fix this up:

```
CREATE TABLE EventData
 (
   ID              int
  ,Name            varchar(50)
  ,Location        varchar(50)
  ,FromDate        datetime
  ,ToDate          datetime
  ,ApprovalStatus  tinyint   --  Foreign key to a lookup table of valid editing statuses
  ,CreatedAt       datetime  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Then define a view:

```
CREATE VIEW ApprovedEventData
AS
SELECT
  ID
 ,Name
 ,Location
 ,FromDate
 ,ToDate
FROM MyTable
WHERE ApprovalStatus = 1  --  Or whatever “Approved” is
```

Every time an entry is created, a row is added.
Every time an entry is changed, a row is added 
At any given point in time, presumably on only one row per ID can be marked as “Approved”. (Managing and maintaining this could be difficult, and is outside the scope of this answer.)

To access all currently approved items:

```
SELECT * from ApprovedEventData
```

To access all items ever entered, by ID in the order they were created (i.e. that new rows indicating status were added):

```
SELECT * from EventData order by ID, ItemCreated
```

Properly speaking, the primary key would be `ID + CreatedAt`, under the assumption that no two editing events for a given ID would happen at the same time. You could toss in column

```
VersionID   int  identity(1,1)  --  Make this the primary key
```

as a standard surrogate key if need be.

If you need fast access to the set of Live Data, you might be able to build a clustered index on the view, but that too can get difficult.

Comment: nice direction, views would help in separating the logic, much better. Btw i am using ORM, if this can help.

Answer (score 1):

why not have an additional bit column which would be an indicator for active or inactive for each id.  you can simply have the old and new records in the same table and only display active records.  A Job can be setup to run everyday which deletes rejected records ONLY.  This will allow you save the old and new records.  You can also have the job delete the old records (assuming you don't need them) if new record was approved.

So what I am trying to say is:
Original Table:

```
ID  Name    Location    FromDate    ToDate  ApprovalStatus  isActive
1   ABCD    London       1-Jan      31-Dec  approved          1
```

Lets say someone edited the entry (your table will look like)-

```
ID  Name    Location    FromDate    ToDate  ApprovalStatus  isActive
1   ABCD    London       1-Jan      31-Dec  approved          0
1   ABCD    London      1-Jan       30-Jun  edited            1
```

Entry was rejected:

```
ID  Name    Location    FromDate    ToDate  ApprovalStatus  isActive
1   ABCD    London       1-Jan      31-Dec  approved          1
1   ABCD    London      1-Jan       30-Jun  rejected          0
```

IF Entry was Approved:

```
ID  Name    Location    FromDate    ToDate  ApprovalStatus  isActive
1   ABCD    London       1-Jan      31-Dec  approved          0
1   ABCD    London       1-Jan       30-Jun  approved         1
```

A SQL Job can be set up to do the following:

```
    DELETE FROM TableName where ApprovalStatus=rejected and isActive=0;
    GO
```

You can delete the approved 0 records after based on the datetime (which i am assuming you may have as you should always consider having an audit field).  If not then carefully delete all approved records with isActive 0.

```
 DELETE FROM TableName where ApprovalStatus=0 and isActive=0;
```

Make sure you do some tests before you do that delete because you may potentially delete a record which is still in the edited phase and has not been rejected or approved.

Comment: If you do not like the process above. Instead of creating a job, you can delete the record as soon as it is rejected in the code itself. And you can delete the old record as soon as it is approved as well. This way you do not have to worry about having a job, and deleting things that should not be deleted.

Comment: nice answer. will try it asap. but in your solution you are suggesting to keep 2 records with same id '1' which is not possible. and if i change the id, how do identify the original record.

Comment: You can use a combination of Name and Location as the identifier and ID can be different.  This can cause a headache though.  Like you said, creating a new table will have alot of duplicates and it may be harder to manage what to display (edited, approved).

Comment: i have implemented a solution in which i have added below columns: parent-id, status in the main table itself, to manage this. but i am not satisfied with the solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new table:

Original Table (keep as is):

```
ID  Name    Location    FromDate    ToDate  ApprovalStatus
1   ABCD    London       1-Jan      31-Dec  approved
2   EFGH    New York     1-Jan      31-Dec  approved
3   IJKL    Berlin       1-Jan      31-Dec  approved
```

New Table After Change Made

```
ID  Name    Location    FromDate    ToDate  ApprovalStatus 
1   ABCD    London       1-Jan      31-Dec  edited
3   IJKL    Berlin       1-Jan      31-Dec  edited
```

New Table After Rejected (You can delete the rejected record if you want)

```
ID  Name    Location    FromDate    ToDate  ApprovalStatus 
1   ABCD    London       1-Jan      31-Dec  edited
3   IJKL    Berlin       1-Jan      31-Dec  rejected
```

New Table After Approved (You can delete the approved record if you want)

```
ID  Name    Location    FromDate    ToDate  ApprovalStatus 
1   ABCD    London       1-Jan      31-Dec  edited
3   IJKL    Berlin       1-Jan      31-Dec  approved
```

WHEN APPROVED:
Update the original table with id 3 the data from the new table and delete the record from new table.

Comment: In this solution,  the new table will ONLY store edited columns.  Approved columns will be updated in the original table and rejected columns will be deleted.

Comment: Btw i am using ORM - nhibernate, if this can help. make things somehow better to manage. i really do not want to go with multi table approach. multi view would be better.